# What happens if I connect to a utf8 MySQL DB table using latin1?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, latin1

Interesting question... if I have a MySQL table with CHARSET=utf8, and I open a connection with latin1 encoding, what happens?

I tried this, and even characters such as ß and æ could be stored and retrieved properly. Those characters are represented with different byte sequences in utf8 and in latin1, so I didn't expect it to work.

Is MySQL doing some kind of on-the-fly translation between character encodings?

Answer (score 3):

You will feel like it works until you connect with another connection charset. Then you will see strange characters and surely regret.

You're storing bytes in the database that only have sense if you read them with utf8 conversion. But you tell mysql that the field is latin, so he won't understand, but he will send them to you anyway (you're the human and he obbeys). As you're connected with utf8, you will read them through this charset and read them ok.

But if the connection changes charset or you try to change the charset of the field later you will be in trouble and will need tricks like this for reading a single field contents:

```
convert(cast(convert(FieldNameMessed using latin1) as binary) using utf8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, mysql does make a chrset conversion, depending on configuration. To change the chrset of your connection, you can use [SET NAMES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) like

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Comment: It depends on setting the default-character-set variable.
When You have Two different encoded databases (different charsets) you will get different fileencodings in the dumps